# Login issues with Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

I'm currently implementing the Google Play Game Service into my game to provide a multiplayer real-time gaming feature (using libgdx and BaseGameUtils).

Everything is working fine on my Nexus 4 with my main Google account (Sign in, creating a room, etc.), call it "A".

To test the automatching and message sending/receiving, I've created a second Google account, call it "B", and added this account to my (factory resetted) Samsung Galaxy Tab.

At first everything worked there also fine - I was able to create a automatched room, send and receive text messages, etc. But after 15 minutes of testing, I wasn't able to login anymore with account "B" on Galaxy Tab. Account "A" on Nexus 4 still works fine.

To rule out any problems with the device, I've added account "A" to my Galaxy Tab and login was successful. I've also added account "B" to my Nexus 4 and the login doesn't work.

After waiting some time (30 minutes), immedetiately the login with account "B" works again on both devices.
And that's my current state: I can do some tests with account "B", but after a short time it get's "blocked" and I have to wait, until I can use it again. Account "A" works always.

While this "blocking" time, I've tried everything: deleting app data/cache, deleting play-service data/cache, unlinking app with my the "B"-account. Nothing works.
Here's the logcat output, if I want to login with account "B" while it is "blocked":

```
07-27 13:20:35.508: I/dul(13742): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException)   caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
07-27 13:20:35.508: I/dul(13742): Retrying request
07-27 13:20:35.808: E/Volley(13742): [1224] ip.a: Unexpected response code 403 for   https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/102515671693140579145
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742): Access Not Configured
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742): ark
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at ams.b(SourceFile:189)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at ams.a(SourceFile:111)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at adz.a(SourceFile:220)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at adz.a(SourceFile:201)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at adi.a(SourceFile:489)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at att.a(SourceFile:221)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at   com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343 )
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/SignInIntentService(13742):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-27 13:20:35.818: E/LoadSelfFragment(16159): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

Of course I *have* a registered client ID, otherwise I couldn't login with account "A" and sometimes with account "B". Of course I added both accounts in the Developer Console to the testing whitelist. And of course I added the correct application ID via resource-link to my manifest.

I don't think it has something to do with my code, because account A never has problems, and account B works "sometimes". Are there any known issues with the testing whitelist? Or do you have any suggestions how to solve that problem? Btw I also don't think that I'm quota restricted, because that would effect both accounts, wouldn't it?

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Have you published your game ? I've seen this sort of thing when testing on emulators, but not on a real device playing a published game.

Comment: Hi, actually the game isn't published (so I have to put the test accounts on the whitelist). I don't test on emulators, only on real devices.

Comment: My point is that you are less likely to see this problem when the game is published. It would probably be quicker to just publish it and try it - I don't see how this can be a problem in your app.

Comment: Any update or real answers to this? I'm experiencing this problem a lot now. It seems to lock a device, not an account. It doesn't matter which of my accounts I try to log in with, the device itself simply won't log in while my other one will. It has also happened to both devices just not simultaneously. I feel like it might have something to do with improper cleaning up. It seems to happen to the device which was left in a room alone when the other device left. Perhaps I just need to tell it to disconnect as well? Seems like it would disconnect just fine when I exit like the other device...

Comment: My answer is Google Play Game Services sucks....It will be years before they get it useful and working fully..seriously!!! Try an alternative. (Sorry, but this has really  jaded me)

Answer (score 3):

This behavior will occur if:

Current user is connected into any room and:

the app is restarted such that it tries to login to Google Services without having gone through the disconnect portion as required by Google Play Services.

I found this happened to me quite regularly (unfortunately for me) as I was figuring out how to pass messages between my Android code and LibGDX code side (my app would just Lock up due to synchronization issues). I also setup some test accounts that I could "cycle" through to avoid being completely locked out of logging in.  However, I found out that if I used Task Manager to Kill the process before restarting the app, 90+ percent of the time, I could continue to use the same account.

If you are updating your code, and load to the device while you are in a Room, this will also earn you the server wrath for approximately 30 minutes for that account.

In short, to keep your account viable:

1) ensure you LeaveRoom prior to updating your code (I have found logging out of PS is not required)
2) If your app locks up... Killing the process via Task Manager (I use Samsung) will most likely let your account continue (you can see in the logcat where it calls the disconnect when you do that) when you start up the app again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So what you say is that I have to disconnect properly from Google Play Services (i.e. leaving the room), BEFORE the adb kills my running appplication?
But why does it also work when you kill it via a Task Manager? I'd think, that task managers internally work like adb when killing a app.. Hmm..

Nevertheless, thank you really much for your answer, I'll give it a try really soon (still very busy atm :() and mark your answer as my accepted answer, if it works!

Comment: I believe the adb install does Not work just like the task manager. When using the task manager, I can track in logcat where it shuts down the service and disconnects from the room (and I get an onPeerLeft notifcation to my other device at that time. If I installed without Killing the process, then no onPeerLeft notification is received)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem as user2446468 ,  some of my testing accounts fail to sign-in after having worked for a couple of hours (after this initial failure they will only work after half an hour or so...)

Here's my Log for this event...

```
08-06 17:03:08.945: D/Volley(21844): [664] ip.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=en_US&platformType=ANDROID NORMAL 20> [lifetime=5926], [size=531], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
08-06 17:03:08.975: D/Volley(21844): [1] ia.b: 5956 ms: [ ] https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=en_US&platformType=ANDROID NORMAL 20
08-06 17:03:09.075: I/dul(21844): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
08-06 17:03:09.075: I/dul(21844): Retrying request
08-06 17:03:09.295: W/AlarmManager(2301): FACTORY_ON= 0
08-06 17:03:09.915: E/Volley(21844): [655] ip.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/11*******************
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844): Access Not Configured
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844): ark
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at ams.b(SourceFile:189)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at ams.a(SourceFile:111)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at adz.a(SourceFile:220)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at adz.a(SourceFile:201)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at adi.a(SourceFile:489)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at att.a(SourceFile:221)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 17:03:09.950: E/SignInIntentService(21844):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
08-06 17:03:09.965: E/LoadSelfFragment(7796): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

UPDATE: I've strong reasons to believe that there really is something "blocking" the sign-in for a period of time (I did some testing , compiled a stress-test version that would constantly attempt to sign-in (with a very reasonable 10sec cooldown in order not to reach any of the request quotas) if sign-in failed... The result was an aprox 30-45min offline period and a full recovery after that (without any user intervention) ... I've got the following theories:

- There may be differently enforced quotas for unpublished apps :(
- This might be a server-side bug when google tries to authenticate if the user is indeed in the testers list for an unpublished app (any googlers around to check it for us?)
- Same thing as the above but for the unpublished app itself (but I doubt it , since it is possible to sign-in with user A and not with user B at a given time)
- There may be some cache built into the local Game Services Activity (caching a wrong client id(maybe a null ptr somewhere) for the APP and thus receiving that 403 error correctly) , if so this is a bug in the Play Game Services API itself, not server side...

Should I discover anything I'll keep you guys posted...

Comment: Hi, I'm also still having the problem (tested atm). Did you try if it works when you publish your app? I'm absolutely busy atm, so I don't have any time to work on my private android projects.

I also think it is a server-side bug. Probably they don't like to have two different accounts logged in with the same IP.

Comment: @user2446468 Unfortunately i'm not authorized to publish this app nor am I authorized (legally) to reuse any code to create a test-app under a different developer account... I'll escalate the issue to try to get some attention to it...

Comment: Small update : I've notice that this issue might also happen (temporary locking the account) if for some reason "google-play-game-services" activity crashes during a transaction ...

Answer (score 0):

I recently started having these problems as well. I think they may be doing some maintenance on their side. I just started using a different testing account and it all started working again. Of course, I am now having other problems. I'm looking into my problem and I'll update you as I find anwers. For now, I suggest simply using a different (or new) testing account (and make sure you rememmber to authorize the account to test under the developer console!)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a tester account added to both devices (through Settings)?

I know that's kind of a dumb question, but I had my tester account on only one device and got the same (very unhelpful) error message.  You can't just assume you can add a tester account to the second device through the regular sign-in flow - it will just fail unless there's already a Google account on the device with tester access.

Comment: Hi, don't know if I unterstand your post correctly. On the first device, I used my standard Google account, added as tester in the developer console.
On the second device, I added the tester account as a second account (beside my standard google account). When I want to login to Google Play Game Services, it asks, which account I want to use (then I use the test account). But I also deleted my main account on this device, so the tester account is the "main" account. Nevertheless, there was always the same error msg.

Comment: I had a device that didn't have a tester account enabled anywhere on the device.  I got the same error message.

But if you have at least one tester account on each device, then your problem is probably something different.